# How to check for json date type of a value from a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, datetime, odata

I have a jsonObject with mixed data type values. I want to recognise their classes so that I can process further.

However, I am unable to check the type of Object when their class is **Json date type.**

*Sample trial code I have*

```
 JSONObject js1 = new JSONObject(
   "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": \"str\", \"dob\":\"/Date(1463667774000+0000)/\"}");

                Iterator<String> keys = js1.keys();
                while(keys.hasNext()){
                    Object aObj = js1.get(keys.next());
                    if(aObj instanceof Integer){
                        System.out.println(aObj+" is Integer");
                    }else if(aObj instanceof String){
                        System.out.println(aObj+"is String");
                    }else if(aObj instanceof Date){
                        System.out.println(aObj+"is Date");
                    }
                }
```

*Result:*

```
1 is Integer
str is String
/Date(1463667774000+9000)/ is String
```

*Expected result:*

```
1 is Integer
str is String
/Date(1463667774000+9000)/ is Date
```

I tried using *EdmDateTime* and *EdmDateTimeOffset* class in org.apache.olingo-olingo-odata2-core-2.0.6.jar but that is not working. 
Still it shows /Date(1463667774000+9000)/ is String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json structures don't hold Date types. You need to convert it yourself.

You could do:

```
    else if(aObj instanceof String) {
        if (aObj.toString().startsWith("/Date")) {
            System.out.println(aObj+" is Date");
        }   
        else
            System.out.println(aObj+" is String");
```

then later

```
        String str = "/Date(1463667774000-9000)/";
        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1")));
```